# jQuery: Using Variables in Selectors

Tags: jquery, variables, css-selectors, selector

Every searches I made only included solutions for variables like this: $('#div'+ id)

I need to delete a row.

```
var row = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('tr#' + id).html();
```

I'd like to use the "row" name instead of "$(this)...remove();"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use .closest, it is safer than all those chained parent calls in case you change the markup which will break the code.

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
row.remove()
```

Answer (score 6):

like

```
$('tr[name='+rowname+']').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just populate the row var with a reference to the row.

```
var row = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('tr#' + id);
var html = $(row).html();
$(row).remove();
```